# Javascript: Format Date and what type of date is it

Tags: javascript, date

How do I format a javascript date to the following format:

```
2022-02-23T17:04:05.6474089-05:00
```

javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ISO 8601 format

You can use [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

`toISOString` returns an UTC time. If you want to include the time offset you can use `moment` for that, passing `true` for `keepOffset` param:

```js
console.log(moment().toISOString(true))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Pipe, toISOString gives me this: 2022-02-28T19:28:00.000Z, I want it like this: 2022-02-23T17:04:05.6474089-05:00

Comment: they are both valid iso strings - why do you need it specifically that?

Comment: @tbjgolden I understand but unfortunately I'm dealing with an external API that wants it exactly like this

Comment: Just edited my answer to include what you want

Answer (score 1):

In ISO Z is equivalent to `+00:00`. JS implementations nowadays always return UTC (`Z`) so this code is safe for an input of instance Date.

```js
const d = new Date()

const toAVerySpecificFormat = (date) => {
  return date.toISOString().replace(/Z$/, "0000+00:00")
}

console.log(toAVerySpecificFormat(d))
```